# How to run changes in the laravel projects in git

Tags: laravel

I'm new in git.
I'm modifying my Laravel project in my project's git folder.
but when I do php artisan serve, changes not work and previous codes run!

Comment: Do you pull your project from github?

Comment: yes I did, but pushed again @gguney

Comment: Not pushing but pulling. If you make changes in your local you should not do anything it will change your code, but if you make changes on remote you must pull the remote changes and it will change your local.

Comment: no , I'm developing it locally @gguney

Comment: So there is nothing to do with git. Can you check that you are changing your local app and running php artisan serve in the same directory

Comment: yes i have done it several times, with visual studio code Terminal, Windows command prompt, windows powershell  and so on ! @gguney

Comment: I think you are doing something wrong. Where are you changing and where do you run php artisan serve because what you said is not logical. You are changing your local app and serving from the same app yet you said it is not changing.

Comment: I have answered to my question @gguney

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem and solved it by :

```
php artisan route:clear
```

The routes got cached